# what is the sscanf format for string "abc 123 456"

Tags: c, scanf

I want to split the string "abc 123 456" into the string ("abc") and 2 numbers (123,456). What is the format should I put in the below code?

```
char *s;
int a,b;
sscanf("acb 123 456", format, s, &a, &b);
```

Comment: You should declare s as an array of chats, not a pointer.

Comment: See the POSIX description of [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html) for all the gory details of how to use `sscanf()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want:

```
"%s%d%d"
```

But you also need to allocate buffer space for the string you extract:

```
char s[100];
int a,b;
sscanf("acb 123 456", "%s%d%d", s, &a, &b);
```

Comment: The initialization of the string is not crucial; `sscanf()` will do that too (though it will simply null terminate it, not zero all the unused spaces). You've not specified how big the string can be; it is a good idea to use `%99s` to read into a 100-byte string (note the off-by-one length!).  It is also a good idea to test the conversion: `if (sscanf("abc 123 456", "%99s %d %d", s, &a, &b) != 3) ...conversion failed...`.

Comment: @Charles, shouldn't it be "%s %d %d"?

Comment: @Ben: The spaces are not critical in this example at least.  The `%s` skips leading spaces, and then stops at the first space in the input; the `%d` operations always skip leading white space.  Adding the spaces won't do any harm here; it won't make any difference.  Sometimes, adding a space does make a difference.  For example, the `%c` conversion specifier does not skip spaces, but if there is a space before it in the format string, then leading white space is skipped and the `%c` matches the first non-white-space character.

Comment: You should include the %99s as Jonathan recommended in production code, and probably edit this answer to reflect that (for a magic number sized s[100] anyway).

Comment: The space is significant in `%99s %d%d`, as it specifies that if 99 characters are read, then there must be at least one character of whitespace prior to the decimal digits in order for sscanf to return 3 (the successful value, in this case).